# Is there any possibility to get datatable row value from xhtml to javabean class

Tags: jsf

I have a data table like below

```
<p:dataTable style="height:600px; width: 100%;border: none;" var="timelineData" value="#{timelineBean.timelineActivities}"   paginator="true"  rows="10" resizableColumns="true" liveResize="true"
                                         paginatorPosition="bottom" paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"  
                                         scrollable="true"  rowsPerPageTemplate="10 20 30">
```

Is there any possibility to get row (rows = "10") value in my bean class.So i can use that value like offset and pass to DB

Comment: Why don't you set that value from your backing bean and access it thus? If you had `rows="#{timelineBean.rows}"`, you have your problem solved don't you?

Comment: The value of the `rows` attribute is a constant value. You can maintain  constants of your interest somewhere in your application and access them through EL, as and when needed. You do not have worry at all about offset and page size, if you happen to use [`lazy`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml) ([`org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel<T>`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.1/org/primefaces/model/LazyDataModel.html)). Both of them will be available in an overloaded method.